# Display and Edit Form in same page base on user ID

Tags: php, mysql

I'm quite new in this PHP programming and already tried looking my issue at this forum but no success.

I have build a simple webform using PHP and stuck when trying to edit form. My form consist of below

1. register html form -  basicallly user fill in the form and hit submit. the form will then go to register.php
2. Register.php - all the field store at database and I also display the form using the SESSION (not call from database) in this page.

Here is my problem start. At the dispay(register.php) I want allow user to edit his/her information and submit again(which i think use update query base on ID). But I truly don't know how to do this.

Can someone advice me or give some simple code for this so that I can have clearer view?

Answer (score 1):

you also must strip slashes for avoiding Sql injection

In previous pages you must store the username from textbox of login
Something like this:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['username']=$_POST['input of login txtbox'];
```

you can just get the condition with user cause you have just one unique user 2 users mustn't have the same user name then just store the username of them in $_SESSION

```
   $connection=Mysql_connect('server','user','pass');
if(array_key_exists('sub2',$_POST))
{
    if(!$connection)
    {
        echo 'connection is invalid';
    }
    else
    {
            Mysql_select_db('Your DB',$connection);
            $pas=$_POST['pass1'];
                    $username=$_POST['username'];
                    $pas=mysql_escape_string($pas);
                    $username=mysql_escape_string($username);

   $query="update user set user='$username'and pass=password('$pas') where  username='".$_SESSION['username'].";
       //some code
    }
```

in your form:

```
    <p><b>User Name:</b><input type="text" name="username" />

    <p><b>Password:</b><input type="password" name="pass1" />
    <input type="submit" name="sub2" value="update"/>
```

[use this site for secure your code](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Comment: thanks for that..but how to based on that user who submitted the form?
in my database, there is one column called user_id(autoincrement)

Comment: you told me that you have used session then it is easy let me update my answer for you

Comment: is this what you wanted? Hope it helped

Comment: maybe a better solution with ID exists I don't know exactly

Comment: Thanks negin. I'm not sure if I understand it correctly. but let me study first as I'm totally new. my read at internet that use the ID..but how to call the ID since my form method is POST.

Comment: If you studied it somewhere please show me the link that used ID.how to call the ID since my form method is POST=>ID is in Mysql and it will increment by 1 then when you delete some of them maybe you will have these IDs:1,5,6,7,... then what you want to do with ID in the form?why you insist on it? you must have a good reason please explain it for me